# A question about use of 为止

Tags: usage

辣椒对我们饮食的影响是否就到此为止呢?

The use of "wei zhi" in this sentence puzzles me. In some contexts it means "until," but I think the sentence basically means, "Does the influence of hot peppers on our diet end here?" I think the author intends a rhetorical question--to convey the idea that the influence of spicy foods is growing.

Does this seem right? Thanks for any insights.

Comment: entered  到此为止 in iciba yet? there find sample sentences with English translations, also explanation from baike, additional suggestions from simply searching net for  到此为止

Comment: Reechen 你是iciba的代理商或者员工？

Answer (score 1):

It is better to learn "到此为止" as one compound word.  For example, 今天的会议就到此为止吧. The meeting of today ends right now. "到此为止" implies that there may be more issues but will be handled next time. It is somehow different from 今天的会议开完了. The meeting of today completed now.

Also it is better to learn "是否就到此为止呢?" also as a whole phrase. This question implies its answer, such as, "显然不是!" Instead of a question, it is a way to emphasize the answer. In English, "Are these all of the problems? No, definitely not."

You also mentioned "until". That is a different usage. Such as "直到...为止. For example, "我们不能回家，直到把这个题目做完为止. We will not go home until the project is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You were right!

到此为止 = to this be stop(ped) = call it a day, stop here

Comment: I'd say "until here as a stop".